# Puppet: How to concatenate variable and a String

Tags: linux, concatenation, puppet

I want to concatenate puppet variable and a string

```
$agents_location='/home/agent2/adikari5'
file { $agents_location+"/filename.zip":

    mode => "0777",
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/filecopy/wso2as-5.2.1.zip',
}
```

As above code I want to concat the $agent_location and rest of the string part to make the path to the file. What is the correct way of doing it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can interpolate variables in a string with `${}`:

```
file { "${agents_locations}/filename.zip":
  ...
}
```

**Note the double quotes**. Without them, the path name will be literally what you wrote, i.e. `${agents_locations}/filename.zip` instead of `/home/agent2/adikari5/filename.zip`.

Documentation reference:
http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation

Comment: You do also have to make sure you use double quote.